# The food basket contained an error

Tags: sentence-construction

This question was asked in my exam:

> The food basket contained (A)/ a dark chocolate, an eclair and a pastry (B)/neatly wrapped in foil paper. (C)/No error

They gave part (B) has an error, but what's the error in it?

Comment: Nice teaser title.

Answer (score 2):

B is in error. *chocolate* as used is non-count. So no article.

> The food basket contained **dark chocolate**, an eclair and a pastry neatly wrapped in foil paper.

But you could write:

> The food basket contained **a dark chocolate donut**, an eclair and a pastry neatly wrapped in foil paper.

where *chocolate* is an adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: Don't you mean A has the error?

Comment: Note that "a chocolate" would be okay (probably due to ellipsis). May be worth touching on why "a dark chocolate" fails where "a chocolate" succeeds.

Comment: @903749457 It's confusing. There are four options but only three letters.

Comment: @LukeSawczak You would have to define what the actual item is. While you can say "a chocolate", there is always an implied "a chocolate (something)".

Comment: @user3169 It is `A`, though — if `A` referred to the first chunk of the sentence then `C` would be associated to "neatly wrapped in foil paper", in which case "No error" would be stranded, and it can't be stranded since it's an option and not part of the sentence. As for "a chocolate (something)" — agreed, but the question is still why not "a dark chocolate (something)" :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I suppose, but then [*The temple is(A)/within a hundred yards(B)/from my house*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149538). You can't tell if "The food basket contained" was assumed to be correct, or if a (D) at the end was omitted.

Comment: Hmm, I see, I see. I guess I haven't seen enough of these to know when to perform "question calculus" and infer missing data. :p