# The temple is(A)/within a hundred yards(B)/from my house

Tags: sentence-construction

The temple is(A)/within a hundred yards(B)/from my house(C)/No error(D)

Correct Answer: D:- as per my exam.

but I think it should be "within hundred yards".
please explain the concept behind as well.
can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

D is correct because you normally use the article with a number: *a/one hundred yards*

This is not the case for *Within walking distance*

Have a look through some of the answers here

[Difference between "hundred", "a hundred", and "one hundred"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/923/difference-between-hundred-a-hundred-and-one-hundred)